# Are there any limitations in using the pod structure in Ember CLI?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-pods

I am planning to move my Ember CLI application to the pod structure. Are there any limitations or disadvantages in the pod structure that I should be aware of?

Comment: last I saw they hadn't implemented it for every type, but beside that, you have to always type -pod

Comment: @Kingpin2k not if you set `  "usePods": true` in your `.ember-cli` ;)

Comment: There are issues with pods in addons. Check repo issues

Comment: Good info Jakeii... Ember-cli is no expertise of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You will have many files with the same name. This may be a problem, depending on your environment.
- Not all types are supported. You have to use the classic structure for those. (But if you use `ember g ...` ember-cli will do this for you.

Other than that: We've switches our app to pods without any problems.

Comment: can you please specify the types that are not supported by pods.

Comment: That would be everything that you might expect to support it from `ember generate --help` but isn't listed in http://www.ember-cli.com/#pods - service, mixin, initializer, ...

Answer (score 2):

The current limitation that I'm facing at the moment is that there is no separate pods structure for ember-data. In my app not all models are strictly bound to one route. So it makes no sense to define the model alongside its route file.

So basically I have to define my models in the global models folder.
It would be nice if we could have multiple pods folders, so for example a data pods, where model, adapter and serializer could be grouped together.

This is also the case with global components which do not have a separate pods folder, but are defined under the pods folder alongside with all the route pods (which doesn't feel right at the moment, but this might change when we move to Ember 2.0 with routable components).

Comment: +1. I've moved my project to pods structure but models don't really fit IMO. It'd be nice if I could tell cli whether to default to a pod generator by type